# Hall $\pi$-subgroups of a normalizer

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group with $A\unlhd G$ and $H\in$ Hall$_\pi$(G)

Consider $N_G(H \cap A)$. Then $H$ is a Hall $\pi$-subgroup of $N_G(H \cap A)$

Let $K$ be another Hall $\pi$-subgroup of $N_G(H \cap A)$

I need to show $K = K(H\cap A)$ and $K\cap A = H \cap A$

$H\cap A \unlhd N_G(H \cap A)$ and $K(H\cap A) \leq N_G(H \cap A)$

Now $|K(H \cap A)| = \dfrac{|K| |H\cap A|}{|K \cap H \cap A|}$ thus $[K(H \cap A) : K] = [H \cap A : K \cap H \cap A]$ is a $\pi$-number as $H$ is a $\pi$-group

$[N_G(H \cap A) : K] = [N_G(H \cap A) : K(H \cap A)][K(H \cap A) : K]$ so $[K(H \cap A) : K]$ is a $\pi'$-number as well. Hence $K = K(H\cap A)$ and $H\cap A \leq K$ and so $H\cap A \leq K \cap A$

I want to prove the other inclusion in the same way by showing $H = H(K \cap A)$ but I am unable to show that $H(K \cap A)$ is a subgroup of $N_G(H \cap A)$

Comment: $H \cap A$ is a Hall $\pi$-subgroup of $A$, so we must have $K \cap A \le H \cap A$.

Comment: I'm still not sure how this follows. I know that $H \cap A$ is a maximal $\pi$-subgroup of $A$ so we have $|K\cap A| \leq |H \cap A|$. How can I be sure that $K\cap A \leq H \cap A$?

Comment: You have already proved that $H \cap A \le K \cap A$.